# Javascript, anyway to do a 'whileFocused' eventListener? (No JQuery)

Tags: javascript, input, onblur, onfocus

Is there a way to implement or simulate a 'while focused' bind on a dom element?
Say log a message every second, starting when onfocus occurs, but stops upon leaving.

Considering this:

```
myinput.addEventListener("focus", function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        console.log('Mouse on:' + this)
    }, 1000);
});
```

the only thing I can think of was using a global variable like:

```
var isfocused = false;
myinput.addEventListener("focus", function(){
    isfocused = true;
    setInterval(function(){
        if (isfocused)
            console.log('Mouse on:' + this)
    }, 1000);
});
```

then adding another listener for onblur to toggle 'isfocused'

But that feels.....just wrong. And plus the setInterval would continue firing off in the background right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the title relates to the question

Comment: Brain was thinking about ways to purge everything inside the function haha. My bad~

Comment: Are you meaning to use [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) which will stop a interval you have created?

Comment: Yea! But is there a possibly more generic solution to do that for any persistent/loop-ish operations? Edit: I actually can't think of any right now. Guess I'm good then, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight improvement to @Scott Schwalbe

```
(function(){
    var intervalId;
    myinput.addEventListener("focus", function(){
        intervalId = setInterval(function(){
            console.log('Mouse on:' + this)
        }, 1000);
    });
    myinput.addEventListener("blur", function(){
        clearInterval(intervalId); 
    });
})();
```

1) Wrap it in Immediately Invoked Function Expression to keep the global variable space pure.

2) The 'unfocus' event is really 'blur'

Answer (score 1):

window.setInterval returns an id for your interval callback. You can then pass in that id to window.clearInterval(id) to stop it. Something like

```
var intervalId;
myinput.addEventListener("focus", function(){
    intervalId = setInterval(function(){
        console.log('Mouse on:' + this)
    }, 1000);
});
myinput.addEventListener("unfocus", function(){
    clearInterval(intervalId);
});
```